How to find the No. Series from the No. Series Code in Business Central?
While creating documents in Business Central, you can choose diferent No. Series:

In this example, I'm using the selected No. Serie in the image ENS-PED. PED80019 was the last document for that No. Serie.
If I use the procedure TryGetNextNo() from Codeunit 396 NoSeriesManagement I can get the next No. in the serie: PED80020.
I want to get ENS-PED and my starting point is PED80019 or PED80020.
How can I find the No. Series ENS-PED from the Document No. PED80019 or PED80020?

For the assembly orders I can solve it by using the "No. Series" default field that is in the header, but I still want to learn how to get the "No. Series" from the "Document No.".

You shouldn't do it like this. Getting number from series is a one way operation. If you need this information then you should store “no. series” in an additional field. Fill this field when series is selected from the list.

Thank you @MakSim you always help me <3
